# Does Intel intrinsics load functions read from cache or RAM?

Tags: intel, sse, intrinsics, avx

Does Intel intrinsics load functions like:

```
  _mm256_load_**
```

read from **cache** or from **RAM** into to the registers?

Thank you!

Comment: If the data is already in cache then it reads from cache, otherwise the data is read from RAM (via cache).

Comment: It doesn't necessarily even generate a load, if the `__m256` value being loaded was already in a register.  But otherwise the question is nonsense.  `vmovaps ymm0, [mem]` is just a normal load, the same as `mov eax, [mem]`, so it will read from cache if the data is cached.  The load doesn't *bypass* the cache or anything like that.  You might as well ask whether `int foo(void) { return global_variable; }` reads from cache or RAM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. As Paul R mentioned the data is loaded either "from cache" or "from memory" (which itself oversimplification), depending on **current state of memory sub-system / hierarchy**.
2. Consider reading following **perfect book**:  https://people.freebsd.org/~lstewart/articles/cpumemory.pdf to obtain basic (and also some advanced) understanding of memory sub-system. You ultimately need to learn minimal theoretical basics before moving forward with practice exercises, especially at such low-level as intrinsics.
3. To make answer complete. There is special type of load which has *hint* to bypass cache and load data "directly" from memory. This is called non-temporal load and corresponding AVX intrinsic is **_mm256_stream_load**_* . This is quite advanced topic, I don't think you really look for thing like that at given point on learning curve.